# Creating a CSV file from a text file

Tags: shell

i have the below text file in this format

```
2015-04-21
00:21:00
5637
5694
12
2015-04-21
00:23:00
5637
5694
12
```

I want to create a csv file like the below one-

```
2015-04-21,00:21:00,5637,5694,12
2015-04-21,00:23:00,5637,5694,12
```

i used the tr and the sed like this-

```
cat file | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

It results in the below way-

```
2015-04-21,00:21:00,5637,5694,12,2015-04-21,00:23:00,5637,5694,12
```

but it doesn't have an new line after the column 5.

Do suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` like so:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%5 ? "," : "\n"'

$ cat test.txt
2015-04-21
00:21:00
5637
5694
12
2015-04-21
00:23:00
5637
5694
12

$ awk 'ORS=NR%5 ? "," : "\n"' test.txt
2015-04-21,00:21:00,5637,5694,12
2015-04-21,00:23:00,5637,5694,12
```

Explanation:

- ORS stands for output record separator
- NR is number of records
- NR % 5 - % is modulo operator. If it is zero (every 5th record), use line feed. Otherwise, use comma

Comment: Wow Zed, This looks awesome. Let me try this and update you.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try it out? You've got two nice answers to select from. When you get a chance, please feel free to accept one of the answers to put closure to your question.

Comment: Yes Zed, this works as expected. I also got this as expected-
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-read-comma-separated-cvsfile/

Comment: Excellent. To put closure to your question, feel free to mark either of the answers as accepted. It's your choice. If you prefer not to mark a question accepted, that's also okay.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution in python

```
fin = open('file','r')
fout = open('outputfile','w')
a=[]
i=0
for line in fin:
    a.append(line.rstrip())
    i+=1
    if i==5:
        fout.write(','.join(a)+'\n')
        a=[]
        i=0
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: Mohit, Do i have to save this file as .py? How can i run this python application?

Comment: save as test.py and then on cmd run `python test.py`